# (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I don't understand why I am unable to create a server with the following code.

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer ( function(req,res){

  res.end('Hello World\n');

});

server.listen(3000,function(){

  console.log("The server is listening on port 3000 now");

});
```

Comment: Do you have something else running on that same port?

Comment: I just checked and there isn't

Comment: Your code as-is works and opens a port listening on port 3000, and displays your console.log when running `node your-file.js`. Do you have any other code?

Comment: If I run the file, I get 'Hello World' but then is seems that the connection is cut off.        If I use curl localhost: 3000 to check I get the error message of connection refused.

Comment: `If I run the file, I get 'Hello World'` - no you don't ... you get *The server is listening on port 3000 now* ... in the BROWSER, or the result of curl, (on the same machine) you'd get `Hello World` - I am assuming you run the server and the "curl" command on the same computer

Comment: What I meant to say was that on the cmd I run **node index.js** I get Hello World. And yes I am running it on the same computer.

Comment: So apparently I had a file that had the same port number. The server now works

Answer (score 1):

if you are using unix system, to list any process listening to the port 3000:

```
lsof -i:3000
```

To kill any process listening to the port 3000:

```
kill $(lsof -t -i:3000)
```

to force violently to kill any process:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:3000)
```

and then run again the script